# I would like to use regex in python to match a US dollar amount

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm pretty new to python and regex, so forgive me if this is elementary. I am trying to match a pattern to allow for unlimited numbers on the left side of the decimal and two on the right. This is the pattern I'm dealing with.

`$44.01Bobby N. ...1111`

It might also be something like.

`$4354.01Bobby N. ...1241`

I am able to match the *44.01* by simply typing this, which is what I want.

`\d*\.\d\d`

However, I end out matching `.11` as well, which I don't want.

Comment: Is there always a dollar sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using `\d*` which matches: **no digit**, one digit or more that one digits, so `.11` is a valid match. To ensure matching at least one digit before the `.` try using `\d+\.\d\d`. The `\d+` matches one or more than one digit.

Comment: That actually would work perfectly in the scenario I'm in given that the data I'm working with would have a 0 to the left of the decimal if I was just dealing with cents. I was working under the assumption I wouldn't have a 0, but in this case, I do. What would I do in the case I didn't have a 0?

Comment: You can also check for the $ (needs escaping)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use curly braces for the right side numbers to indicate you want exactly 2 instances of `\d`—but, of course, if you want to save a keystroke and readability isn't an issue, using `\d\d` works as well:

```
\d+\.\d{2}
```